# expression expected type unit, but it already does

Tags: ocaml, try-with

```
let _ =
    try ("hello"; ()) with
    | _ -> print_endline "hi"
```

Compiling this tells me that `("hello"; ())` 'should have type unit'

In fact, I get the same warning with this code

```
let _ = "hello"; ()
```

or this code

```
let _ = ("hello"; ())
```

But it **does** have type `unit` ... doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression :

```
 let f  = "hello";1;;
```

Triggers the warning :

```
 this expression should have type unit - around "hello" string.
```

This is because you are trying to return a first value via "hello", and then you return `1` meaning that ocaml must disregard "hello".
 if you replace it by `unit` - meaning "here I return nothing", it will be ok.

The expression :

```
let f = (); 1;;
```

raises no warning and `f` is an `int`.

So the warning you are getting is related to the inner code of your expression, not to the type of the expression you have written.

```
let f = "hello";();;
```

The compiler warns you that you compute something that you disregard after that ("hello" is never used, and the return value is of `f` is `()`). But, as you have noted, `f` has type `unit`.

In `utop` :

```
let _ = try ("hello"; ()) with
    | _ -> print_endline "hi";;
```

You get :

```
Characters 13-20:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

which locates exactly to the position of `"hello"` string - but does not locate to `("hello"; ())`. `("hello"; ())` has type unit, exactly like `print_endline "hi"`.

The warning is just about the fact that the expression that should be instead of `"hello";` is expected to have type unit.

Comment: To make your intention explicit and suppress the warning, write `ignore "hello"`.